# PHP Administration Login

Tags: php, ajax

I have setup a 3 page php login system.  first page is login.php. it loads users input to the content.php and content.php will check the username and password. if fails, it will direct the user to the loginfail.php

If i just try to open the content.php without loading login.php first. I will be directed to loginfail.php

The design is using the post method on login.php and just simply checking the $_POST value inside content.php.

Here is my question : is this a secure design for protecting the content.php file ? it seemed no one will have the access to content.php unless they load login.php and get the username and password right.

Comment: "Secure" is a relative term. If you're checking a hard coded value it will be safe enough to protect your content from the Average Joe, but not safe enough to protect you from brute forcing.

Answer (score 1):

you can do all in a single page like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../inc/db.php");
if((isset($_POST['action']))and($_POST['action']=="login")){
$qu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name`='$_POST[uname]' and `password`='$_POST[pass]' LIMIT 1;");
if(mysql_num_rows($qu)!=0){
$uobj = mysql_fetch_object($qu);
    $_SESSION["user"] = 'U';
    $_SESSION["username"] = $uobj->user_name;
    $_SESSION["fname"] = $uobj->full_name;
    $_SESSION["id"] = $uobj->uid;
    header("location:index.php");
}else{
    header("location:login.php?message=wrongpass");
}

}

?>

<form method=post><table border=0>
<tr><td style='width:100px;'>user name</td><td><input type=text name=uname ></td></tr>
<tr><td>pass</td><td><input type=password name=pass ></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><input type=submit name=submit value=' login ' style='width:120px;'></td></tr>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='login'>
</table></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite safe in my opinion yes.
It's difficult to say more without seeing the code.

Now maybe you should restrain number of tries with an IP because : http://i129.photobucket.com/albums/p203/Zelinko/Motivational%20Pictures/ATXNXOTI3MHPD6FS4MOF5IZHKKPBLSVV.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how safe you want to get. Its safe enough for a small private app, or something to be used by a few people, but i wouldn't use it in a bank site.

Because you are saving the password in the content.php file directly I guess (it sounds a lot like a homework I had on my first year at the university), if someone gets access to read the file through ftp for example, you would compromise the password. Also, you could brute force the password quite easily if you don't have a blocking method.

To add a bit of security you could hash the password in a database and add a limit to the amount of failures a connection can have.

Comment: haha you are right. i did put password in my content.php, but this is just a test. later on i want to load data from database to check username and password. want to create a forum or discussion board ...etc.

Comment: If you want to get really tricky you can even hash the password with js before sending to content.php and then only check the hash. that way the password is never sent visibly, in case there is someone in the middle watching...if you are really paranoid hahaha.